# How to fix "User not authorized to perfom rds:DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOption. AWS RDS"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am looking for a json code to add `rds:DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOption` policy to my IAM AWS.just like the code given below to add `rds:DescribeDBEngineVersions` policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rds:DescribeDBEngineVersions",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Action` is a list, so you can add new element to it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:DescribeDBEngineVersions",
                "rds:DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```